# 3 classes imbalanced and hierarchical classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, unbalanced-classes, multi-class

I need to classift a dataset with 3 classes:
A - 85% of the data
B - 10% of the data
C - 5% of the data
Where C is a subset of B.
What should be the best way to approach it?

Comment: How would you approach the problem if you had balanced classes? You’ve tagged this with [tag:random-forest]. Are you determined to use such a model?

Comment: @Dave I would probably use RF, but the question here is more about to to deal with the hierarchy , and whether in this case there are specific ways to deal with the imbalance (rather than the "regular" oversampling/SMOTE)

Comment: Why do you have to do anything special to address the imbalance?

Comment: @Maybe because two minority classes are hierarchical. Do you have any response as to what will be the best way to address classification in this scenario? (e.g classify A/B and then B/C, etc?)

Comment: 1. If "C" is subset of "B" why not have two classifiers? One A vs (B+C) and one B vs C? 2. You may want to consider distributionally robust optimization (DRO) such that we minimize the worst-case training loss over pre-defined groups.

Comment: @usεr11852 I also thought about One A vs (B+C) and one B vs C. So in that case, P(A) = P(A according to 1st classifier) , P(B) = P(B according to 1st classifier) * P(B according to 2nd classifier) and P(C) = P(C according to 1st classifier) * P(C according to 2nd classifier)? Are there additional ways to approach it?